# Is it possible to unsubscribe from a MtGox API channel using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, api, socket.io

The following code does not seem to do anything. Is there a way of unsubscribing?

```
var MTGOX  = 'https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox';
var conn = io.connect(MTGOX);
conn.emit({ 
  'channel':'d5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f',
  'op':'mtgox.unsubscribe'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Streaming#op:subscribe_and_op:unsubscribe shows the op name as just "unsubscribe" whereas you have "mtgox.unsubscribe".  Can you try without the prefix, and/or let us know where you got that prefix from?

Comment: Yes, I originally tried `unsubscribe`. It does not work either. I found `mtgox.unsubscribe` in some example code.

Answer (score 2):

The Mt.Gox API responds to "message" events, so you should be using Socket.IO's `send` command.

```
conn.send({
    "channel": "d5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f",
    "op": "unsubscribe"
});
```

To *unsubscribe* from a channel, send the op "unsubscribe". To *subscribe*, send the op "mtgox.subscribe" [(as listed on the bitcoin.it wiki)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Streaming#Direct_commands).

This is the alternative method (for clarification):

```
conn.emit('message', {
    "channel": "d5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f",
    "op": "unsubscribe"
});
```

Comment: `conn.send({})` doesn't work for me. I'm getting error/remark  `"Unknown command"` and in debug object: `{data_raw: "[object Object]"}`. I tried to `JSON.stringify` the argument, then it works. However you are absolutely right about `conn.emit('message', {})`, without the `message` as first argument it doesn't unsubscribe  anything.